# iPad background thread NSAutoReleasePool confusion about [object release]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an app where I import a bunch of data and I want to to happen on a background thread. This was working well for a small amount of data but now it seems I am running into this error midway through the parsing and importing of large amounts of my data into Core Data:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

Here is the call to the background thread:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(importAllData) withObject:nil];
```

Here is an example of what I am doing in my code:

```
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // load manufactuers from DB
    NSFetchRequest *crequest    = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *manufacturer = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Manufacturer" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [crequest setEntity:manufacturer];
    NSError *cerror=nil;;
    NSArray *manufacturers = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:crequest error:&cerror]mutableCopy];
    [crequest release];

for (int m=0; m < [manufacturers count]; m++) { 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:kClientListURL, [[manufacturers objectAtIndex:m]ManufacturerID]]];

            ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
            [request startSynchronous];
            NSError *error = [request error];
            if (!error) {

                NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
                NSArray *items = [responseString JSONValue];

                NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
                NSNumberFormatter *dec  = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
                [dec setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

                for (int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++) 
                {

                    Client *entity = (Client*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Client" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
                    [entity setCompanyName:[[items objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"CompanyName"]];
                    // set a bunch of other properties
                    [entity setManufacturer:[manufacturers objectAtIndex:m]];

                    statusMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"importing client: %@", entity.CompanyName];
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setStatus) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                }

                [f release];
                [dec release];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"JSON parsing failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]]);
            }

            NSError *entityerror;
            if (![managedObjectContext save:&entityerror]) {
                //  //Handle the error.
                NSLog(@"\n\n\n Error saving clients: %@ \n\n\n\n",entityerror);
            }
    }
    //More data importing code

    [pool release];
```

As I said this was working fine for a small amount of data but now in he simulator it throws bad access errors at random points.

Then I read this article which confused me:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease

Do I not need to release my objects if they are inside of the NSAutoReleasePool?  Am I causing them to be released twice at some point?

If I remove the release statements I get potential leaks errors when building using Command-Shift-A?

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but why are you using threading when you have ASIHTTPRequest at your disposal. Why not make use of ASIHTTPrequest's asynchronous functionality?

Comment: Well I want to update the UI while I am processing the returned request response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are:

- If you are the owner, you need to either call `[object release]` or `[object autorelease]`. The later will delegate the release call to the NSAutoReleasePool, when the pool gets flushed or released.
- You are an owner if you called `[object retain]` or if you got the object through a method that has either `alloc` or `copy` in its name.
- If you got the object from a method that has neither `alloc` nor `copy` in its name and you haven't retained it you must not call `release` or `autorelease` on it (except in the *very* rare case that the documentations states that you *are* the owner).

So yes, if you got an autoreleased object and you call release on it you are over-releasing it. The effects are various but almost always lead to a crash, normally with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. You can debug this by setting the [NSZombieEnabled environment variable](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH7-SW3). That way, whenever an object is deallocated it is replaced by a dummy that knows what object lived at that address before and can then tell you which object got over-released.

But reading through your code I didn't spot any immediately obvious problem, but I don't know Core Data (which you seem to be using) well enough. Another possibility is a threading/timing issue. Also, you said that's not the whole method ? Maybe the error is in the missing part.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, problem it seems was setting a NSString on the main thread to show status messages as I imported data, I'll have to adjust the way I am handling that - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that importAllData is the method you are using.  If so, you are missing the : at the end in your call.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(importAllData) withObject:nil];
```

should be

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(importAllData:) withObject:nil];
```

Hope that helps!